# if statement for returning minimum date value in a dynamic range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This might be easy for many but i need an help. I have the following formula, which searches minimum date in dynamic range.

```
=MIN(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(AF4);COLUMN(AF4))&":af"& (MIN(IF(A4:A108="";ROW(A4:A108))))))
```

:
I wanted to add an if statement which should do following: If there is a date value in the range, it should return  minimum date but If there are no date values in the range, then it should show the empty string.

How can I add this if statement to my formula?

Comment: `=IFERROR(MIN(a4:a108),"")`? This might work if there are only text values, but Excel won't be able to differentiate between a date and another numeric value.

Comment: So there may be a mixture of dates and other non-date numerical values in the range??

Comment: yes, range lets say from J4 to J8. J4,J5,J6, can have string "N/A" and J7,J8 can have dates. then formula should return min of these. If J4,J5,J6,J7,J8 are all N/A then formula should return empty string